# Rx async is not executing

Tags: java, rx-java

would  like to perform a request async  with RxJava. But can execute the Request.add(). Can you help  me pass this junit please?

```
public class Rizze_debug_Rxjava_Test extends METRICS_JUNIT{


    @Test 
    public void testR2_JEOR(){

        logger.info("trace 1 ");        
        Observable<String> obs = Observable.create((Subscriber<? super String> s) -> {
            try {

                logger.info("//processsing");       
                Request.add();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                s.onError(e);
            }       

            logger.info("//done");
            s.onNext("done");
            s.onCompleted();
        });
        logger.info("trace 2"); 
        obs.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());


        assertEquals(1,Request.i);
        logger.info("trace 3"); 
    }


    public static class Request{
        public static int i =0;
        public static void add(){
            i++;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We must subscribe() in order to run it :

```
public class Rizze_debug_Rxjava_Test extends METRICS_JUNIT {

    @Test
    public void testR2_JEOR() {

        logger.info("trace 1 ");
        Observable<String> obs = Observable.create((Subscriber<? super String> s) -> {
            try {

                logger.info("//processsing");
                Request.add();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                s.onError(e);
            }

            logger.info("//done");
            s.onNext("done");
            s.onCompleted();
        });
        logger.info("trace 2");
        obs.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe();

        assertEquals(1, Request.i);
        logger.info("trace 3");
    }

    public static class Request {
        public static int i = 0;

        public static void add() {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An Observable like this, by itself, is just describing the asynchronous processing pipeline you want to execute. It is a cold Observable, and it won't start emitting data until there is a subscription, so you need to call one form of subscribe or another.

Note that here the emissions will be very quick upon subscription since it basically executes a loop on subscription, but for truly asynchronous processes that can emit an item with a delay, this approach of just calling `subscribe()` won't work because the control will return immediately to the next row in the test, which will probably terminate before the async processing has happened.

For these cases there is a special `Subscriber`,  the `TestSubscriber`, which will allow you to block the test until the Observable completes or errors, then assert the emissions /errors. You should look into it!